# How to get bitmap from painted panel in C#

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, system.graphics

I have a panel and I use it's Graphics gr = panel1.CreateGraphics() to draw lines and other stuff. I need to get pixel color of the point where mouse is clicked, so I decided to use GetPixel method of Bitmap. I create bitmap this way:

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(width, height);            
panel1.DrawToBitmap(b, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
b.Save("D:/aaa.bmp");
```

but I get only white rectangle even if I've drawn anything. What's the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836338/saving-panel-as-an-image

Comment: Minimize the form and restore it to see why you should not use CreateGraphics().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only things that are drawn in the `Paint` event will be rendered by `DrawToBitmap`. Instead of explicitly call `panel1.CreateGraphics()`, handle the `Paint` event of the panel and do your drawing using `e.Graphics`.